# Implementing "JSON Merge Patch" in ASP.NET Core - best way do differentiate between null and not defined property

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, api-design

I would like to create and endpoint conforming to "JSON Merge Patch" https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396

Please do not confuse it with "JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Patch"
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902

However, I have a slight problem with differentiating between two situations in request:

- removal of property value, here  email value is being removed:

  ```json
    {
        surname: "Kowalski"
        email: null
    }
  ```
- property not included because client simply does not want to update it, here email is not included because it should not be updated:

  ```json
    {
        surname: "Kowalski"
    }
  ```

The problem arises because in both situations after model binding email would have value null.

Do you have suggestion how this might be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I come to this thread with the same question. My solution is similar to the 'CodeFuller' one but more complete as it covers API documentation with swagger and better because uses less code. It also uses [`System.text.json` instead of the `Newtonsoft`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to) library.

1. Define your model by taking advantaging of [the existent `Optional` struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.optional-1?view=roslyn-dotnet) (no need to create a new `OptionalValue` class)

   ```
   {
       public string Surname { get; set; }

       [JsonConverter(typeof(OptionalConverter<string>))]
       public Optional<string> Email { get; set; } = default;
   }
   ```
2. Tell Swagger (if applicable) to format as a string input/type for a better client experience:

   `c.MapType<Optional<string>>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string" });`
3. Add a custom JSON converter based on `System.text.json`:

   ```
   public class OptionalConverter<T> : JsonConverter<Optional<T>>
       {
           // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to
           public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) =>
               typeToConvert == typeof(Optional<T>);

           public override Optional<T> Read(
               ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
               Type typeToConvert,
               JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
               new Optional<T>(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options));

           public override void Write(
               Utf8JsonWriter writer,
               Optional<T> value,
               JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
               throw new NotImplementedException("OptionalValue is not suppose to be written");
       }
   ```
4. That is. Now you have 3 states:

   ```
   [HttpPatch]
   [Consumes("application/merge-patch+json")]
   public void Patch([FromBody]SomeModel data)
   {
       if (data.Email.HasValue)
       {
           //  Email presents in Json
           if (data.Email.Value == null)
           {
               //  Email should be removed
           }
           else
           {
               //  Email should be updated
           }
       }
       else
       {
           //  Email does not present in Json and should not be affected
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You need 3 different states for email value here:

1. Filled value for update (e.g. `test@mail.com`)
2. `null` value if email should be removed
3. Missing value if email should not be touched.

So the problem actually is how to express these 3 states in `string` property of your model. You can't do this with just raw `string` property because `null` value and missing value will conflict as you correctly described.
Solution is to use some flag that indicates whether the value was provided in the request. You could either have this flag as another property in your model or create a simple wrapper over `string`, very similar to `Nullable<T>` class.
I suggest creation of simple generic `OptionalValue<T>` class:

```
public class OptionalValue<T>
{
    private T value;
    public T Value
    {
        get => value;

        set
        {
            HasValue = true;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public bool HasValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need custom `JsonConverter` that could deserialize usual json value to `OptionalValue<T>`:

```
class OptionalValueConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(OptionalValue<T>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return new OptionalValue<T>
        {
            Value = (T) reader.Value,
        };
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Your model will look something like this:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(OptionalValueConverter<string>))]
    public OptionalValue<string> Email { get; set; } = new OptionalValue<string>();
}
```

Note that you assign Email with empty `OptionalValue<string>()`. If input json does not contains `email` value than `Email` property will keep it `OptionalValue` with `HasValue` set to `false`.
If input json contains some `email`, even `null`, then `OptionalValueConverter` will create instance of `OptionalValue` with `HasValue` set to `true`.

Now in controller action you could determine any of 3 states for `email`:

```
[HttpPatch]
public void Patch([FromBody]SomeModel data)
{
    if (data.Email.HasValue)
    {
        //  Email presents in Json
        if (data.Email.Value == null)
        {
            //  Email should be removed
        }
        else
        {
            //  Email should be updated
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //  Email does not present in Json and should not be affected
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to work, but then my generated Swagger also contains the "HasValue" property in the Model. Is it possible to hide it ?

Comment: Quite a separate problem. Please post it as new question with Swagger tag.

Comment: Ok thank you. Could you please answer anoher question ? Let's say I implement your solution. if someone then calls this API in a C# project and want to do partial updates. How should he do it ? He will work with a "SomeModel" class with all properties that he will serialize to JSON. So he will also have specific code to differentiate ignored properties and properties he want to set to null. Is it correct ? Do you think it is the best solution to for partial update ? I don't know if I should use JSON PATCH instead... (Or the solution of r0bnet with props that I want to set to null in headers)

Comment: If you use POCO model in your client, you need somehow to indicate whether missing value should be serialized as `null` (if value should be removed) or should not be serialized at all (if value should not be touched). Consider using anonymous objects when building the request and fill only the properties that should be touched (updated or removed).

Comment: Thank you. I think I will finally use a query parameter to specify the fields I want to update, and ignore the others...

Answer (score 3):

Could you use the JsonMergePatch library?
https://github.com/Morcatko/Morcatko.AspNetCore.JsonMergePatch

The usage is very simple:

```
[HttpPatch]
[Consumes(JsonMergePatchDocument.ContentType)]
public void Patch([FromBody] JsonMergePatchDocument<Model> patch)
{
   ...
   patch.ApplyTo(backendModel);
   ...
}
```

It appears to support setting some properties to null, and leaving other properties untouched.  Internally, the JsonMergePatchDocument creates a JsonPatch document, with one OperationType.Replace for each item in the request.
https://github.com/Morcatko/Morcatko.AspNetCore.JsonMergePatch/blob/master/src/Morcatko.AspNetCore.JsonMergePatch/Formatters/JsonMergePatchInputFormatter.cs

Answer (score 2):

This is a particular problem when using a language that doesn't support a distinction between `undefined` and `null` like JavaScript and TypeScript do. There are other options which you might consider:

- use PUT (not always feasible)
- for strings use `""` to delete it because an empty string is often not a valid value (also not always feasible)
- add an extra custom header to indicate if you really want to delete that value with a default value set to false (e.g. `X-MYAPP-SET-EMAIL=true` will delete email if it is null). Downside is that this could blow up your request and pain for client developers

Each option from above has its own drawbacks so think carefully before you decide which way you go.